DateTime Changes On Different Timezone
I run into an issue, don't know how to resolve this at the moment. So here it's, I've a date column in database as follows:
31-Oct-24

If I check with the following query:
select TO_CHAR(m.START_DATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') START_DATE from UserDetails m;

It returns the following:
00:00:00

That means there is no time part. We have an existing WPF project that gets the data along with date with the following: This is a SOAP service that gets passed to the WPF project
SOAP Service:
DataSet tempDataSet = new DataSet();

using (OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
{
  adapter.ReturnProviderSpecificTypes = false;
  adapter.Fill(tempDataSet);
}

tempDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["START_DATE"];

In the WPF project, it has the data with the following with no conversion:
DataTable table = SRO.FindData(LoginData.Ticket, LoginData.Session, LoginData.ActAsRoleId, Where);

When the date comes into the WPF project and the client machine has UTC-5 time zone, then the date converts into this:
30-Oct-24 02:00:00

That means the date saved in database, gets converted to the system time zone. I am not sure why this is happening, I tried to convert the date to string to enforce the date (It can't be converted as it's a DateTime type) as well as force to omit the date from DateTime. But nothing prevents it to getting into system time zone. Is there any way to resolve this as I can't do any changes in the WPF project, so preferring to handle this from the SOAP Services itself?
Update 1: Here's how the DateTime is returned from the procedure.


That conversion doesn't make sense, does it? If the unspecified time is midnight and your zone has offset -5, then how could it ever result in 02:00 ?

This is what we are facing now. When two users have different time zone, this occurs. Weird! We expect the exact date that's in database. The problem appears when the date comes into the WPF project.

I faintly remember that wcf might do an auto- conversion to local time but I'll try and find a source for that later. But even if so, this seems broken to me. You say soap service. Is it wcf or something different?

Yes, that's WCF that I am referring as SOAP service. Any way to enforce in the SOAP services rather than any modification in the client, would be great @Fildor.

I was thinking to create a new DataSet with new column types, converting DateTime to string and pass all data to there. Is it something doable @Fildor?

First, dates aren't text and have no format, either in the database or C#. And SOAP uses the ISO8601 format by default to serialize dates. WCF already uses it. So what is the actual database type and actual date value? 30-Oct-24 is a Y2K bug, not an Oracle or .NET date

In Oracle database, it's created as date column. In C#, I get it in the correct format. Problem is, it gets converted to WPF project.

WCF doesn't use DataSet at all - that was a lazy hack used 15-20 years ago to create "dynamic" services instead of using an array of DTOs. WCF services support strongly typed objects and handle dates automatically. What are the actual database and DTO types, and what's the actual WCF code, especially the contract and data classes?

@user8512043 dates have no format. This isn't up to discussion or interpretation. Your query is simply wrong, returning buggy text instead of the actual date value. You can't claim this isn't October 24, 2030 or 1930. Remove TO_CHAR entirely and you'll get a DateTime binary value in your DataTable. Which can't be used with WCF or SOAP in general without jumping through hoops

In my analysis, I just see a DataTable method that returns strong-typed data and DateTime as well. It gets the data from a procedure and just wraps data into the DataSet. In the query, there is no conversion at all with T0_CHAR. I used it to demonstrate there is no time involved @Panagiotis Kanavos.

You're analyzing hacky code that would be frowned upon even in 2002, with ASMX services. SOAP uses stronly typed data objects and DataTable was used by people that didn't want to specify the DTOs. The rest of the arguments are wrong too and here is no conversion at all with T0_CHAR is beyond wrong - you don't even know what that string means when you could easily just get a valid DateTime by not casting anything. Your very question proves there was a bad conversion beyond doubt

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

What is the DateTime.Kind value on the WPF app and how are the dates displayed? If  UTC time gets converted to local time in a timezone west of the UK, the date itself will change.

The date is displayed as 07/30/2024, I don't see anything with this DateTime.Kind. Do I've specify something with this in the app itself? @Panagiotis Kanavos. Should I use this to retrieve the one you asked DateTime value = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Local);.

I'm Not sure of what is going on there as you did not share the code show where you are saving/storing the datetime, But here is my advice

While saving/storing, use dateTime.UtcNow in place of dateTime.Now this will save you a lot of stress regarding time zoning, This way you have a single unique time
Now to solve your current problem  use
string mytime = yourDateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");

you can create an extension method on dateTime
public static class DateEx
{
public static string ConvertToUTCString(this dateTime)
{
return dateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
}
}


so use it anywhere on any dateTime, All you need to do is
yourDateTime.ConvertToUTCString();

example:  string mytime =  yourDateTime.ConvertToUTCString();
And it will return a utcstring datetime

Any solution to do the same in the DataSet rather creating another variable for this?

you can create an extension method on dateTime to do this

public static class DateEx  {
public static string DateToUTC(this dateTime){
return dateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
}
}

I just edited it

WCF already uses ISO8601 which, by the way, includes the offset. Just using UTC isn't a panacea, losing important information. In any case if the OP hadn't converted the date to an ambiguous string they'd get a DateTime with an Unknown Kind. Converting that to UTC only needs a call to DateTime.SpecifyKind()

@EgbuleGoodluck the problem may well remain even with UTC (especially with UTC) if the client doesn't check the DateTime's Kind and displays it as local time. Converting  2024-12-18T00:00Z in any country west of the UK will result in 2024-12-17T..... Unless it's summer, when the UK offset is +1:00

Not my downvote and manually serializing to YYYY-MM-DD could be a solution, however hacky - if had the actual code. In SOAP, date-only values are serialized as xs:Date but WCF doesn't support this. The Type Mapping docs say that xs:date is mapped to String. Old articles from WCF's heyday resort to that, or use custom Date objects that serialize to YYYY-MM-DD.
